# RewriteRule trouble with optional trailing slash

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use the following RewriteRule to direct URLs such as http://mysite.com/calendar/ to specific pages such as /calendar.php

```
RewriteRule ^calendar/?$ /calendar.php [NC,L]
```

This works fine without the trailing slash (http://mysite.com/calendar), but if I include the final slash (eg. http://mysite.com/calendar/) my javascript and stylesheets don't get included. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure On What It Is Your Needing. But It Seems A Simple preg_replace will do you. eg:

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/calendar/";

preg_replace('/calendar/', '/news/', $url);

//$url now =  http://mysite.com/news/
//OR
$url = "http://mysite.com/calendar/calendar.php";

preg_replace('/calendar/', '/news/', $url);

//$url now = http://mysite.com/news/news.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser in looking for the assets inside the (virtual) `/calandar` folder.

Instead of using relative urls, use root-relative urls.

```
e.g.
<link href="main.css" ...>
would become 
<link href="/main.css" ...>
and 
<script src="folder/file.js" ...>
would become
<script src="/folder/file.js" ...>
```